# add www in URL if no subdomain but exception with some folders

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to add "www." to URLs if it doesn't contain "www." after "http://"; but it shouldn't get added if any file is requested from some specific folders.

Here is what I have tried.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} ^/exception_dir(.)*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

With this code, presently, the "exception_dir" is NOT being exempted from redirection. What I am missing?

And how to write RewriteCond and/or RewriteRule if there are multiple directories to be exempted? Do I need to write both RewriteCond and RewriteRule for each of the directories separately?

Comment: What about just using 1 RewriteRule: `RewriteRule ^(?!exception_dir/)(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]` ? It looks enough.

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev, it looks promising, though I haven't tried it because I can only see for 1 exception-directory. So, for multiple directories I will need to write this lines for each directory which will make the rule longer. than the answer given by Panama Jack. What is your opinion?

Comment: You can add alternatives after `|` in a non-capturing group: `RewriteRule ^(?!(?:exception_dir|mydir)/)(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]`. But maybe Panama Jack's answer is "cleaner", and you do not have to mess up with regexes too much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your rules like this. In this example I also excluded 2 directories. You can do 1 or several directories.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exception_dir1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exception_dir2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working smoothly. By the way, I am quite good at programming but I always get confused when constructing regular expressions. Can you please suggest some good resource to learn regex; book or a web resource? I know about mod_rewrite documentation page on Apache's website but it seemed like reference to me, not for learning from beginning.

Comment: it's cool. I still learn new stuff everyday about regex. I'm not an expert either, but have just learned over time. These sites are helpful http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and https://regex101.com/